# restricting access to AWS EC2 instance through the bastion

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am running a Linux EC2 instance and have a bastion host running.

What I would like is to only allow access to the EC2 instances through this bastion as a jump server.

I struggle with how to create the EC2 instance so that only connection through the bastion is allowed. Currently., I can just simply SSH into it.

Comment: One option would be to create a VPC with one ore more private subnets and public subnet for the bastion host. Put the bastion host in the public subnet, everything else in the private subnets.

Comment: This post might be helpful - https://towardsdatascience.com/connecting-to-an-ec2-instance-in-a-private-subnet-on-aws-38a3b86f58fb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The typical configuration would be:

- An Amazon EC2 instance in a **public subnet** acting as a Bastion, with a Security Group (`Bastion-SG`) that permits access from your IP address only
- An Amazon EC2 instance in a **private subnet** (preferably) with a Security Group (`App-SG`) that only permits inbound SSH (port 22) connections from `Bastion-SG`

That is, the Security group on the app instance specifically refers to `Bastion-SG` and only allows SSH connections from the bastion.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I managed to finally set all this up :)